# What's wrong with this 'proof' that $g\circ f$ is an identity arrow then $f\circ g$ is too.

Tags: functions

Say we have $f:A\to B,g:B\to A,g\circ f = id_A$.

Suppose that $$f\circ g \neq id_B.$$

Then
$$g\circ(f\circ g)\neq g\circ id_B$$
$$(g\circ f)\circ g \neq g$$
$$id_A\circ g\neq g$$
$$g \neq g.$$

is a contradiction. Hence, our assumption is false and so $f\circ g = id_B$.

Comment: You can't left-multiply a non-equality with something and obtain a non-equality. Compare with $2 \neq 1 \not\Longrightarrow 0\cdot 2 \neq 0\cdot 1$.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's obvious. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your proof is that $f \neq g$ implying that $h\circ f \neq h\circ g$.

Example: $A = \mathbb{Z}$, $B = \{1\}$. Then $f(n) = 1$ and $g(1) = 1$ satisfies
$$
f \circ g = id_B
$$
but
$$
g\circ f \neq id_A
$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $g\circ f = id_A$, it does not necessarily follow that $f\circ g = id_B$

For counterexample, consider $A=\mathbb{R}^1$ and $B=\mathbb{R}^2$, $f=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $g=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}$

You have then that $g\circ f = g\cdot f = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}=id_A$

*but*

$f\circ g = f\cdot g = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\neq id_B$

Comment: Yes, certainly - I was aware of counter-examples, my question was rather 'where is the mistake in my reasoning which leads to this absurdity?'. But darij ginberg's comment answered that

Comment: Exactly. The question ensures already its conclusion is false. It is asked about the mistake on its "proof"